# How to search for files, directories or grep(ag) from a directory inside a project with helm-projectile?

Tags: helm, projectile, ag

`helm-projectile` makes you set a project before trying to find files or directories, or searching through files with `ag`.  All the searches are then based from the project root.

How does one start, for example, a `helm-projectile-ag` search from within a subdirectory of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is quite sparse for `helm` and `helm-projectile` so I'll leave this here for posterity.

One way of searching through files in a particular directory would be:

`C-c p d` find the directory of your choice, then
`C-s` allows you to specify a pattern to search for within that directory.

Something similar can be done by searching for files with `C-c p f`, highlighting some with `C-space` and then using `C-s` to search through the selected files.

[This link](https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) provides more examples but isn't always easy to follow.